# Convert URI value to accessible GET variable

Tags: php, apache2

I click a link with the following path: `href="/book/45"`

With ModRewrite in Apache2:

```
# Enable URI Routing
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which redirects to my index.php:

```
function getCurrentUri()
{
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, 0)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    $uri = filter_var($uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    return $uri;
}

$uri = getCurrentUri();
$routes = array();
$routes = explode('/', $uri);
if ($routes[1] == "book") {
    ...
    require('../views/books.php?id=$routes[2]');
    break;
    ...
}
```

I get a 500 Internal server error.  Without the `?id=$routes[2]` the page loads fine.

My objective is to be able to reference the id with `$_GET['id'];` in the file books.php.

Comment: I solved this by passing the variable.

``if($routes[1] == "book"){
       $book_id = $routes[2];
       require('../views/books.php');
       break;
   }``  

This works because the script at ``/views/books.php`` will be able to see the variable for ``$book_id``

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make your require like this. The PHP require function expects a file and not an "URL like". You can try this hack :

```
$_GET['id'] = $routes[2];
require('../views/books.php');
```

Comment: Can a header redirect be applied here?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Build a route to do X.  In this example, it would view book with an ID tag #45

``<a href="/book/45">View this Book</a>``